# In a chain of equalities/inequalities, is each line referring to the previous one?

Tags: soft-question, notation

In a chain of equalities/inequalities, or equalities/containments:
$$\begin{align*}
A & = B\\
  & \subsetneq C\\
  &  = D
\end{align*}$$
to which element is the last part refering to? In other words, is $D = A$?

Comment: No, I would read it like $A=B, B\subsetneq C, C=D$. Thus $A\subsetneq D$

Comment: This is also my call.  People I have asked seem to fail at reaching a consensus, some arguying that any line should be read as $A$ followed by the line (hence the "soft-question" tag).  I'm searching for references ruling for one way or the other---the conclusion here being that this style should be avoided, of course.

Comment: Imagine these were numbers, how would you read $a = b < c = d$? I think it is pretty straight forward. I don't know anyone who would read it in an other way.

Comment: This also holds for number.  Their reasoning is not entirely faulty:  think of your equations as being laid over multiple lines, then you read $=d$.  What can be on the left hand side? Well, the only thing which is not a right hand side value, that is, $a$.  Frankly, I'd love to just say "Well that's bonkers," but it seems that *actual* people think this way.

Comment: It's conceivable that someone could mean that, and it's not bonkers, but in published mathematical work it never does mean that; it always means $A=B; B\subsetneq C; C=D$.